# Passwordless SSH not working - keys copied and permissions set

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I know this question has been asked, but I'm certain I've done what all the other answers suggest.

Machine A:

- used **keygen -t rsa** to create **id_rsa.pub** in **~/.ssh/**
- copied Machine A's **id_rsa.pub** to Machine B user's home directory
- Made the file permissions of **id_rsa.pub** *600*

Machine B

- added Machine A's pub key to authorised_keys and authorised_keys2: **cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorised_keys2**
- made the file permissions of **id_rsa.pub** *600*

I've also ensured both the *.ssh* directories have the permission *700* on both machine A and B.

If I try to login to machine B from machine A, I get asked for the password, not the ssh pass phrase.

I've got the root users on both machines to talk to each other using password-less ssh, but I can't get a normal user to do it.

Do the user names have to be the same on both sides? Or is there some setting else where I've missed.

Machine A is a Ubuntu 10.04 virtual machine running inside VirtualBox on a Windows 7 PC, Machine B is a dedicated Ubuntu 9.10 server

**UPDATE** : I've run ssh with the option *-vvv*, which provides many many lines of output, but this is the last few commands:

```
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/pete/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host '192.168.1.19' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pete/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 504/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1015
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1063
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/pete/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/pete/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7ffe1baab9d0)
debug2: key: /home/pete/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1127
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pete/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/pete/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/pete/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1495
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pete/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/pete/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Im sure you meant .ssh/authorized_keys? Cause that's the correct name for the file.

Comment: The name of the `authorized_keys` file is set in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.  If it's still failing, running your `ssh` command with `-vvv` can help find the problems.

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, I've updated that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your keys; it will create any necessary files/directories and fix any broken permissions along the way.

Comment: I agree. Using ssh-copy-id removes almost all the general pitfalls you encounter when doing key-based authentication. If it still doesn't work it's either that it's not enabled in the sshd_config or selinux.

Answer (score 2):

file name has to be: `authorized_keys2` and it should be `chmod 600`.

```
~/.ssh (700)
~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 (600)
~/.ssh/id_rsa (600)
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (644)
```

*** UPDATE *** : provide output of following (from a remote server):

```
ls -ld ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_key*
```

Is SELinux enabled? (use: `getenforce`), are you getting `Permissive` or `Enfrocing`?

Comment: All of my keys are in a plain authorized_keys file http://serverfault.com/a/116193/9517.

Comment: 'getenforce' is currently not installed. Do I need it?